# Line, branch and method coverages for Javascript?

Tags: javascript

We're looking to collect some analytics on our javascript unit test coverage. We are looking not only for line coverage (for instance that's all JSCover does) but also branch and method coverages. I've done some minor google-fu and haven't found too much that has quite what I'm looking for. Has anyone come across something that handles these three areas (or a combination of tools)?

Answer (score 1):

[JSCover](http://tntim96.github.com/JSCover/) now supports branch coverage